# HSQLDB + junit : intermittent "connection exception: closed"

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hsqldb, maven-surefire-plugin

I am seeing a strange problem when using HSQLDB in my unit test.

I have a unit test using in-memory HSQLDB which is failing intermittently with the following:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: closed
```

along with

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: connection does not exist
```

My suspicion is that the in-memory DB is somehow persisting between the different test runs.

My test looks like this:

```
private static final String DRIVER = "org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test2";

@BeforeClass
public static void init() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    populateDatabase();
}

private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, user);
}

private static void populateDatabase() throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = getConnection(); Statement statement = connection
            .createStatement()) {
        statement.execute(
                "CREATE TABLE employee (name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "
                        + " age INT NOT NULL, outputcol FLOAT)");
        connection.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@AfterClass
public static void destroy() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection(URL + ";shutdown=true", user, user);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        statement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE employee");
        connection.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The fact that the error is inconsistent points to something hanging around in memory between test runs, which is bizarre.

I have tried:

- adding the 'shutdown=true' option to the destroy method
- making the DB name in the URL different in each class
- using @After and @AfterClass for cleaning up the connection
- changing the name of the hsqldb each time the test is run

Note that the test should create a DB in memory, then pass the credentials to the class under test, which uses those credentials to connect via `DriverManager`.  After the test is over, we drop the tables and basically want to then empty and destroy the DB.

I'm running these tests from the command line with `mvn clean install`.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of `;shutdown=true` added to a URL is as follows:

- it is effective on the first connection to the database, not on subsequent connections
- when the last connection is closed (by calling the close() method), the database is also shutdown

You can execute `SHUTDOWN` as an SQL statement in your destroy() method, instead of counting on all connections getting closed.